# Staining + sealing cedar for outdoors

Tags: wood, woodworking, sealing, stain

I've made an outdoor cabinet out of cedar. I like the natural look, but I used various other wood species like white oak as "moulding" and am thinking I would like a uniform look.

I would like the cedar to last as it will be outside all the time (in Florida).

I take it the order of operations is to stain then seal. I've never stained anything before, is there anything I should look out for? Anything I should take in to account to minimize the maintenance (re-sealing) of the cedar. Product recommendations are welcome if you have any.